# remote connection from Linux to Vista

Tags: linux, windows-vista, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I wanna use my windows desktop on Linux RedHat,
I installed RDesktop on my linux,and set remote connections on windows Vista,but it doesn't work.
I tried remote connection between my linux & my friend's Mac,it worked out; think some settings/services needed on windows,maybe?! :-/
any ideas?
cheers

Comment: Are we talking RDP or VNC here?

Comment: yes,i am talking about RDP

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated Remote Desktop on Vista? (Right-click on my computer -> Properties -> Remote Settings -> Allow Connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop)

Does your edition of Vista support Remote Desktop? (Starter, Home Basic and Home Premium don't.)

Can the machines see each other on the network? (Ping them.)

Comment: a. yeah,it is activated,
b. it s supported(Business)
c. no,they couldn't

Comment: Then c is the reason why it doesn't work. :)

Comment: genius! :))
that s why we wondering ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try a different tool, one that is independent of specific direct connections. I like team viewer. It's free for personal use, and it figures out all the "fun" network stuff for you, and all you need to do is leave it running on the windows machine. There is a version, i believe for every OS now. Other than that, since teamviewer was the first and only Remote desktop solution I've tried that works every time, I can't help. Windows remote desktop was always buggy back in the day.